# Ubuntu 20.04 / Gnome 3.36.2 forgets dual-monitor settings when switching between PCs via KVM/KVMP switch

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, multi-monitor

I have a Display Port KVM / KVMP switch to switch between two PCs (Ubuntu 20.04 , Windows 10). Whenever I switch back from the Windows 10 PC to the Ubuntu 20.04 I have to restore my dual monitor settings via the "Displays" settings or switch one monitor off and on again to get both monitors in Joined / Dual-Screen mode again. This sometimes messes up my application windows.

Interesting observation: If I have the Settings -> Displays dialog open while switching between machines, the gnome-control-center process crashes with SIGSEGV and Ubuntu wants to report an internal error to the developers.

I ran a Ubuntu 20.04 live USB system on the Windows 10 PC and got the same behaviour. So this seems not to be an hardware error as both PCs use different GPUs, CPUs and motherboards.

Is there a way to "lock" a display configuration such that the system will not switch back to one monitor mode if the second one is not detected?

GPU is a Intel HD Graphics 520 if this matters.

(Bonus points for anyone how can point me to a way to debug this behavior to report to developers)

Comment: I have this same issue and I have a feeling this functions the way it does to prevent another problem from happening. It may be some time before this is fixed.